# Reemplazar palabra exacta en PHP array

Tags: php, array

Quisiera saber como puedo reemplazar exactamente palabras en `PHP`, actualmente tengo esto:

```
$string = "Despues de tomar no maneje, es mejor llamar un taxi";

$exceptions = array(
    "de"  => "DE", 
    "es" => "ES"
);

$conver = str_replace(array_keys($exceptions), $exceptions, $string);

//OUTPUT: DEspuES DE tomar no maneje, ES mejor llamar un taxi
```

Lo que deseo es que cambie solo si la palabra coincide y no en todos los caracteres que encuentre:

Ejem:

> Despues DE tomar no maneje, ES mejor llamar un taxi

Comment: En realidad lo que deberías de hacer es descomponer tu string con la función split y te quedara un arreglo, que deberas recorrerlo y cambiar los elementos que coincidan con lo que requieres reemplazar.

Comment: Una posible solución _(quizá no la mejor)_  sería dar espacios a su `array` `$exceptions` tanto para su clave como para su valor.  `" de"  => " DE" `

Comment: Para la búsqueda podrías utilizar la función array_search() http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-search.php . Lo que si está te devuelve la key del resultado, ya con eso deberías hacer un array_replace() con la key obtenida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar expresiones regulares

```
<?php 
$string = "Despues de tomar no maneje, es mejor llamar un taxi";

$exceptions = array(
    "de"  => "DE", 
    "es" => "ES"
);

echo reemplazar($string,$exceptions);

function reemplazar($cadena,$excepciones)
{
    $stringRet = $cadena;
    foreach ($excepciones as $key => $value) {
        $stringRet = preg_replace("/\b$key\b/", $value, $stringRet);
    }
    return $stringRet;
}
```

**Entrada:**

> Despues de tomar no maneje, es mejor llamar un taxi

**Salida:**

> Despues DE tomar no maneje, ES mejor llamar un taxi

Comment: ¿Por qué  un voto negativo?

Answer (score 1):

Como comentas, el reemplazo se debe realizar únicamente si la palabra coincide, esta es una solución:

```
$string = "Despues de tomar no maneje, es mejor llamar un taxi";

$exceptions = array(
    "de"  => "DE", 
    "es" => "ES"
);

$strarray = explode(' ', $string);

$newString = "";
for ($var = 0; $var < sizeof($strarray); $var++) {      




   foreach($exceptions as $exception => $exceptionToReplace) {     
      if(strpos($exception, $strarray[$var]) !== False){            
          $newString .= $exceptionToReplace.' ';
          $noChange = false;
          break;
        } else {        
          // NO change                    
          $noChange = true;
        }                 
    }  

    if($noChange)
     $newString .= $strarray[$var].' ';


}

echo $newString;
```

Tendrás como resultado:

> Despues DE tomar no maneje, ES mejor llamar un taxi

Comment: Sin embargo frase como yo no lo se, aunque creía que sí, no las tomará en cuenta dado que la frase es 'se,' quizá como complemento de la respuesta debería eliminar caracteres que pueden afectar la comparación.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien amigo, se aceptan mejoras a mi código, saludos!